# How can WCF service detect client disconnection

Tags: c#, wcf, http, networking, error-handling

I have the following complete program (which can be copy-pasted-built-and-run. you might have to add a few references). The objective of the program is for the service to detect (e.g. receive a `SocketException` or `IOException` of some form or as attempted in the code via some event handling) that a connected client (tested/test from web-browser) has disconnected before the response has been fully delivered (see `return` statements in method `Talk(string animal)`). To reproduce the issue, there is a configurable parameter (see `new AnimalTalkService(3)`) which dictates how long the service will take to respond to a given request. And within this time frame, i can close the browser in order to raise the client-disconnection event (see method `ClientDisconnected()` in class `ClientConnectionTracker`). I am unable to get any exceptions thrown into the implementation of the service or get the `Closed` and `Faulted` events triggered. Would someone have an idea on how to   go about to (implement) get the desired effect?

```
// Code:

using System;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestClientDisconnect
{
    class ClientConnectionTracker : IChannelInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(IClientChannel channel)
        {
            channel.Closed += ClientDisconnected;
            channel.Faulted += ClientDisconnected;
        }

        private void ClientDisconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client Disconnected");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    class ClientConnectionTrackerEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ChannelInitializers.Add(new ClientConnectionTracker());
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    interface IAnimalTalkService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/{animal}", Method = "GET")]
        string Talk(string animal);
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    class AnimalTalkService : IAnimalTalkService
    {
        private int delayInSeconds;

        public AnimalTalkService(int delayInSeconds = 0)
        {
            this.delayInSeconds = delayInSeconds;
        }

        public string Talk(string animal)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating sentence for animal {0} ...", animal);
            if (delayInSeconds > 0)
            {
                // Simulate heavy duty work:
                Thread.Sleep(1000 * delayInSeconds);
            }

            switch(animal.ToLower())
            {
                case "sheep":
                    return "baa";
                case "dog":
                    return "woof";
                case "cat":
                    return "miao";
                default:
                    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AnimalTalkService serviceInstance = new AnimalTalkService(3);
            Uri address = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:1234/");
            WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(serviceInstance, address);
            WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
            ServiceEndpoint endPoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IAnimalTalkService), binding, "");
            endPoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior() { DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json });
            endPoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new ClientConnectionTrackerEndpointBehavior());
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Service is running at {0}. Press Enter key to exit", host.BaseAddresses[0]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Closing the browser will not fire client-disconnection event. This will work only when you call ((ICommunicationObject)client.CallbackChannel).Close(); method explicitly from your client.

Comment: @Vasanthan: Faulted should be called in case there is no graceful termination on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

The word "disconnection" implies a session, isn't it?

The best way, in my opinion, to have methods, that explicitly creates and terminates the session using an explicit session id (here I used an arbitrary type):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWebService
{
    [OperationContract]
    SessionId BeginNewSession();
    [OperationContract]
    void DoSomething(SessionId id, ...);
    [OperationContract]
    void EndSession(SessionId id);
}
```

This is certainly recommended for HTTP protocol, which doesn't support transport-level sessions.

In this case you can write another class, that will housekeep outdated sessions which haven't been closed.

In case you use a binding that supports transport-level sessions, there is another option - to set up session-bound service instance management (and use corresponding binding), implement `IDisposable` interface in the service class and place the related code inside `Dispose()` method:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class TheService : IService, IDisposable
{
    ...
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // code of session termination
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally you can combine both options by marking the explicit session-terminating method with `[OperationContract(IsTerminating = true)]` attribute:

```
[ServiceContract(..., SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(IsTerminating = true)]
    void Close();
...
}
```